# electron-build fails with ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE

Tags: electron, electron-builder

**goal**

I want to build an electron app ON a windows Machine for a Rasperry PI 4 running Raspbian32

**configuration**

```
"linux": {
        "target" : [
            {
                "target": "AppImage",
                "arch": ["armv7l"]
            }
        ]
    },
```

**calling**

"build-dist-lin": "webpack --mode production && electron-builder -l  --config .env.json",

**returned ERROR**

> cannot get, wait  error=Get
> "https://service.electron.build/find-build-agent?no-cache=1ghlrte":
> dial tcp 51.15.76.176:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond.
> attempt=0
> waitTime=2
> Error: C:\A\Repo\test\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE

**No Leads**

There is no further information in this log to know where then ... it goes wrong. In the same env.json I also have a Windows Configuration part which runs perfectly well with calling it with -w. So that means that the configuration is probably ok. And that means it fails somewhere else.

full log:

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\A\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\A\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build-dist-lin'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild-dist-lin', 'build-dist-lin', 'postbuild-dist-lin' ]
5 info lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~prebuild-dist-lin: testingtest@0.0.39
6 info lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: testingtest@0.0.39
7 verbose lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: PATH: C:\A\Tools\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\A\Repo\testingtestplayer\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\a\tools\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\a\tools\Git\cmd;C:\Users\edward.deleau\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\a\tools\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\edward.deleau\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\edward.deleau\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\edward.deleau\.dotnet\tools
9 verbose lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: CWD: C:\A\Repo\testingtestplayer
10 silly lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack --mode production && electron-builder -l --config .env.json'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle testingtest@0.0.39~build-dist-lin: Failed to exec build-dist-lin script
13 verbose stack Error: testingtest@0.0.39 build-dist-lin: `webpack --mode production && electron-builder -l --config .env.json`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\A\Tools\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\A\Tools\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid testingtest@0.0.39
15 verbose cwd C:\A\Repo\testingtestplayer
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\A\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\A\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-dist-lin"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error testingtest@0.0.39 build-dist-lin: `webpack --mode production && electron-builder -l --config .env.json`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the testingtest@0.0.39 build-dist-lin script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the electron builder. Since the free service host associated with the electron builder is unavailable and there by it refuses the connection. You could monitor the issue thread from the below link. This issue has been watched along for a long time I believe.

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3569

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is indeed the reason, though not a good reason. So im looking for an alternative. I manage to build on a rasbian32 pi 4 myself. But since this code goes to a windows based teamcity build server... my problem is that the sqlite extension does require a local compilation. So a cross-build on Ubuntu will fail because the call to electron-builder will call the "after-builds" but this will compile against x64 instead of armv7.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem that such issue will be fixed anytime soon, as we can see from the amount of (mostly open) GitHub issues that have been opened from users that are trying to deal with such problem in the past months:

- [service.electron.build is unavailable](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-build-service/issues/5)
- [Error: Cannot get, wait error=Get https://service.electron.build/find-build-agent](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-build-service/issues/9)
- [service.electron.build is unavailable - Urgently please suggest an alternate](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-build-service/issues/8)
- [Local build service not detected](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-build-service/issues/7)
- [Unable to build AppImage on Windows - service.electron.build](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4318)
- [Connection to remote builder refused, while building linux package](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3569)

That said, I used the following workarond using Docker that made me able to build a Linux redistributable `.deb` package for my Electron App from Windows 10 in less than 5 minutes:

- Install Docker ([link](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/))
- Download the [electronuserland/builder](https://hub.docker.com/r/electronuserland/builder/) Docker image with the following console command:

`docker pull electronuserland/builder`

- From the Electron project's root folder (such as `C:\MyApp`), type the following command-line command to run the container and map the Electron project's root folder to the `/project` virtual path:

`docker run -rm -ti -v C:\MyApp\:/project -w /project electronuserland/builder`

- From inside the container, type the following commands to upgrade the Electron project's Yarn packages, globally install the electron-builder package and build the Linux redistributable package:

`cd /project`

`yarn upgrade`

`yarn global add electron-builder`

`electron-builder -l`

If everything went smooth, you should be able to locate your `MyApp.deb` file (or `rpm`, `AppImage`, or anything you've configured within the electron-builder's `package.json` file) inside the Electron project's `/dist/` folder.

For further info about this whole procedure and a bit of background, check out [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/electron-build-linux-package-from-windows/) on my blog.

Comment: Useful answer and blog, thank you, it worked. For some reason though, this broke my windows build script (said `'electron-builder' is not recognized as an internal or external command`).

Comment: Fixed above by deleting `node_modules` followed by  `npm install`